# Action icon not appear in toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, toolbar, navigationcontroller

Good Day

I'm working on app that use navigation component I setup my toolbar icons but it's didn't appear 
 so I tried to follow these guide [here](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar#ActionItems) [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#create_a_toolbar)to fix the issue but still not appearing
here is **my fragment code**

```
public class myFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_community_timeline, container, false);

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(view);
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph()).build();
    Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.timeline_toolbar);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController, appBarConfiguration);


}
```

**Xml file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".User.Community.CommunityTimelineFragment">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/timeline_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:menu="@menu/user_menu"
        app:title="@string/timeline" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**my menu**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/add_company"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_company"
        android:title="@string/add_company"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/fiter_bodcast"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_bodcast"
        android:title="@string/filter_setting"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/add_question"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_question"
        android:title="@string/add_question"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

**please anyone know why this issue is happend**

Answer (score 0):

Try to create all the views in your `onCreateView` method.

Instead of this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_community_timeline, container, false);

}
```

You should do this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_community_timeline, container, false);

    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(view);
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph()).build();
    Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.timeline_toolbar);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController, appBarConfiguration);

    return view;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I move to onCreateview but it's  this line `NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(view);`cases runtime error even when I change it to `NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(getActiviry(), R.id.nav_host_fragment);` @garritfra